# Cell segment with not obvious edge

Tags: python, image, image-processing, segment

What is the other way to find the segment when the image is hard to do watershed ?
Is it any algorithm to be implemented on the sophisticated image like 
[Tumor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfRxZ.png) ??
I've tried using threshold to separate the nucleus and the others, but it seem to be inefficient. Seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkBSV.png).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe with a research group of 5 people I can make sure you get a solid answer in 3~5 years!

Comment: Could you even say what result you expect ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think it’s the best way to learn it. But it’s a homework that is closed to the deadline.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would like to separate the kernel of cell and turn it into ground truth image.

Comment: @J.Hsieh: ground truth must be done by hand !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah that’s the final representation, but the main thing I want to do is to mark all the nucleus of cells. Then turn it into ground truth. Sorry about not explaining well.

Comment: @J.Hsieh: this is still an unexploitable description of the task. Show us the ground truth.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Here is the goal : https://imgur.com/gallery/aLZsN

Comment: This is not achievable by image processing algorithms. Go for deep learning.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks a lot ! BTW, Is there other method that can do it approximate to the goal without using deep learning?

Comment: This image is very difficult.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah! The professor said it’s hardest one to accomplish.